# Interpreting confidece interval qqPlot of a multiple regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, outliers, qq-plot

Hello I have a problem when trying to interpret a multiple linear regression graph and the qqPlot() function. I'm trying to do this with an example data of at least 28.000 obs.

I used R to make the analysis but i'm stuck with the confidence interval of this graph.

My code in R:

```
regression <- lm(IMC ~ Peso + Edad + Talla, data = pacientes)
car::qqPlot(regression, main="QQ Plot")
```

[image]

I don't know why the line it is not inside in the Confidence interval. It's very strange for me, can someone help me?